# Creating a Timer to run a program periodically

Tags: python, timer

I've created a program which edits a .txt file. This .txt file is used as a source of data for our website. These data change every hour. So, how can I make the python program run automatically every hour? I'm just a beginner, sorry.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Comment: For Windows, use "Scheduled Task"

http://drupal.org/node/31506

Comment: Oh. Thank you! I just discovered Scheduled Task now.

Answer (score 4):

If its windows

[Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

For command-line usage, you can schedule with the [at command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx). I'll add the [schtasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744%28WS.10%29.aspx) command which is the replacement in newer MS OS.

If its unix base then you can use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 2):

For Linux and Unix, use crontab command to schedule your Python script.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm

For Windows, use "Scheduled Task"

http://drupal.org/node/31506

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use Task Scheduler. Unfortunately, i**t's not immediately obvious how to create a task that repeats with a time period** since it is normally used to schedule things by a time of day, date, day of week, or system state. Here are the instructions to set up a periodic task.

1. Create a new task. Here you can put the command to run, whether that is an executable, batch file, or other command.
2. Open the new task's properties.
3. Go to the Triggers tab
4. Add a new Trigger
5. Set when you want the task to first run ("At log on" is a good idea if it needs an interactive user).
6. If you want it wait a bit, you can specify a delay in minutes
7. Check "Repeat task every:"
8. In the drop down, you can select some values, or type your own. Note that on most versions of windows, you can only specify it in terms or minutes, hours, or days. The range of allowed values is between 1 minute and 31 days.
9. Set the duration (Indefinitely if you want it to run as long as the computer is on.
10. Click OK

[image: Task Scheduler New Trigger Dialog]

Congrats! You can poke around the other settings to see things like how it will handle task failures and other things.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is with a cron job - It is a unix system that is made for running scripts at certain times.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron for more information. Hourly is a pretty easy one to set up.

This way, all your program does is the logic (updating the txt file), and you dont need to write the hourly code.